# Php xml parsing for element value

Tags: php

i have the following xml returned from a jsp call

```
<assumption name="test" id="34" description="vector description" is_shared="no" vector_type="Prepay">
<userVector>
<vectorType>"Prepay"</vectorType>
<ppydefTypeCode>"CDR"</ppydefTypeCode>
<ppydefVector>
<vectorName>"test"</vectorName>
<vectorSeasoning>No</vectorSeasoning>
<vectorPeriod>"6 12"</vectorPeriod>
<vectorData>"7 4"</vectorData>
</ppydefVector>
</userVector>
</assumption>
```

What is the best way to retrieve the vectorType information and vectorName using php .

I tried something similar but was not sure how to grab the node value in php

```
foreach ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('userVector') as $vectorRow)
        {

            $vectorType = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('vectorType');

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName('vectorType')` will return a `DOMNodeList` that you'll additionally have to iterate through. You can save each element's value to a variable by accessing their `nodeValue` fields.

```
foreach ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('userVector') as $vectorRow){
    $vectorTypes = $vectorRow->getElementsByTagName('vectorType');
    foreach ($vectorTypes as $vectorTypeElement){
        $vectorType = $vectorTypeElement->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i check if the vectorType element exist or not

Comment: Technically we have to assume that there could be multiple vectorTypes, so you'd check whether sizeof($vectorTypes) is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sx = new SimpleXMLElement($XMLData);
echo $sx->xpath('/assumption/userVector/vectorType')[0];
echo $sx->xpath('/assumption/userVector/ppydefVector/vectorName')[0];
```

Outputs:

```
"Prepay"
"test"
```

Comment: No worries, hope it helped :)